# GnuCash QFX importer chooses wrong Transfer account

Tags: gnucash

When importing a QFX file from my bank into my checking account, the importer matches about 75% of the transactions to the same, incorrect Transfer account (an Income account). This includes deposits, withdrawals, almost everything. Is there a way I can tell GnuCash to just send everything to the "Imbalance" account?

Answer (score 0):

GnuCash learns which transactions belong in which accounts through Bayesian matching. However I don't find the matching engine to be very helpful for my business accounts because I make a lot of purchases from the same retailer that go into different expense categories. In that case I need to match my transactions manually. Since it's a learning algorithm, you can keep telling it that all of the imported transactions match with 'Imbalance' and eventually it should just match everything with that account. I still have to manually change a few each time I import, but it's just a few now.

Another option (which I have not yet tried) is to [turn off Bayesian matching](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/12848/32770).